# Scraping using SELENIUM/BS4

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from this page https://www.flashscore.pl/druzyna/ajax/8UOvIwnb/tabela

How can I separate results with ";"  ??
How can I choose exactly the data I need ??

the data is dynamic

Results

```
 ['1.Ajax20153261:548WWWWP']
```

expected result ( separate ; and miss few rows value 20 and value 48 in this example)

```
Ajax;15;3;2;61:5;W;W;W;W;P'
```

code below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests
from time import sleep
import re
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.flashscore.pl/druzyna/ajax/8UOvIwnb/tabela/")
sleep(10)
page = driver.page_source
soup = BS(page,'html.parser')
content3 = soup.find('div',{'class':'ui-table__body'})
content_list3 = content3.find_all('div',{'class':'tableCellFormIcon 
tableCellFormIcon--TBD'})
res = []
for i in content3:
   line = i.text.split()[0]
   if re.search('Ajax', line):
       line = line.replace("?", "")
       res.append(line)

print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your problem?

```py
content3 = soup.find('div',{'class':'ui-table__body'})
content_list3 = content3.find_all('div',{'class':'tableCellFormIcon tableCellFormIcon--TBD'})

content_list3 = content3.find_all('div',{'class':'tableCellFormIcon', 'title': re.compile('Ajax*')})
res = []
for i in content_list3:    
    line = i.text
    line = line.replace("?", "")
    res.append(line)

res = ";".join(res)
print(res)
```

Instead of uniting all text fields inside the selection and then searching for Ajax, I selected only those divs that have "Ajax" in their title and got their texts one by one. Then you can join them with a separator of preference.

Comment: your result is ";W;W;W;W;P;P;P;W;P;;P" and i need  Ajax;15;3;2;61:5;W;W;W;W;P'. Thanks